# Working with XLWT in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using the Pydev plugin for eclipse to create a small python script. I need to write some data into excell sheets using python .Searching on the internet ,i got xlwt to be the best solution for this .
I downloaded and unpacked the package for xlwt and installed it using easy_install.But still after this i am not able to import the package into my pydev project in eclipse .
Is there something that I am missing here ?

If not xlwt ,is there some other way in which I can write data to excell ?

Comment: I tried running the same script in IDLE ,it says no such module as xlwt.

Comment: It seems it wasn't properly installed or easy_install didn't do its work properly... try just using `pip install xlwt` -- as suggested in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt and see if the import works then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the thing working .Turns out XLWT dooesnt support Python 3.X ,they have a different version XLWT-future for3.X versions. The new one is working now .